# AutoClick somente em class dentro de class

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de realizar um autoclick sequenciado em apenas um link por por vez e somente na class="mobile" que tiver uma class="check-handler". Agradeço a quem me ajudar pois já tentei vários scripts mas até agora nada.

```
(A)<div class="clicked mobile" id="container">
   <div class="check-handler" data-id="000" data-url="http://www.xxx.com">    

(B)<div class="mobile" id="container">                                   
   <div class="check-handler" data-id="111" data-url="http://www.mmm.com">

(C)<div class="mobile" id="container">                                   
   <div class="check-handler" data-id="222" data-url="http://www.uuu.com">

if ($('.mobile #container .check-handler').is(':visible')) 
    setTimeout(function(){$('.mobile #container .check-handler').click();},5000);
```

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Na página existe vários blocos mas eu preciso de um autoclick somente nos blocos igual a opção "B". Meu pensamento é: Seria possível criar um código que funcionasse o autoclick somente se a class=x estivesse abaixo da class=y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui a resposta através de outro site de Javascript.

```
$(document).ready(

function() {

setTimeout(
function () {

$('#container:not(.clicked.mobile) .check-handler').click();


}, 3000);});
```